# Turn back bricks in memory game

Tags: javascript

I'm making a memory game and i have generated a table with cards and you can click in them so they turn around with different images. Now i want to turn them back after some second or something. I guess i should use setTimeOut but i dont know how.

**Some of my code so far:**

```
turnBrick: function(link, img, pic) {

        link.onclick = function(e) {

            if(img.getAttribute("src") == "pics/0.png") {
                img.setAttribute("src", "pics/" + Memory.arrayRandom[pic - 1] + ".png");


            }

        }
    }
```

Note: link is the brick clicked, img i just to check if not clicked and pic is in what order the method is run (like first time, or second time etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Write a JavaScript function to turn the brick back over, then call it with

```
setTimeout('TurnBrickOver()', 3000)
```

which will call the **turn the brick over** function in 3 (3000 milliseconds)